# Jqgrid Filtertoolbar based by color or another column value or cell class

Tags: database, jqgrid, formatting

I have a table with some data coming from the DB.
The complexity is that I'm making some calculation with Javascript I'm coloring some cells based on the result of my calculations (red background, green background, or bold font, etc).
The result is a colored table with also some hidden columns I use for making my formulas.

So, I would like to apply a filter toolbar row that will filter rows using three possibilities:
Filter by cell color otherwise filter column based on a value on another column, or maybe filter by class.
In my example the filter will be applied only on Margin Columns
For example (I'm simplifying because my table is more complex but the concept is a table like this one):

```
| Item | Buy Price | Sell Price | Margin $            | Margin %           | (my columns)
|      |           |            | Red/Green (select)  | Red/Green (select) | (filter toolbar)
```

Is possible to make a "local" filter using the color of cells?
Or can I filter all rows on each column based on a value on another column
My table is built using JSON datatype but the filter should be converted to operate locally, is also possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the code I'm using for showing data…
All data comes from a DB using PHP, and I'm applying local coloring based on some easy comparison..
I would like to have a local search based on values.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var grid = $("#tbl_result");

grid.jqGrid({
    url:'grids/evaluate_prices.php',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['hidden_id_item', 'Item', 'Best Price', 'Supplier1', 'Supplier2', 'Supplier3'],
    colModel :[
        { name:'hidden_id_item', index:'hidden_id_item', hidden:true, key:true },
        { name:'item', index:'item', width:215, search:false},
        { name:'best_price', index:'best_price', width:73, align:"center", sorttype:'number', formatter:'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 4 }, search:false},
        { name:'supplier1', index:'supplier1', width:75, align:"center", sorttype:'number', stype: 'select', searchoptions: {value:':;1:Best'} },
        { name:'supplier2', index:'supplier1', width:75, align:"center", sorttype:'number', stype: 'select', searchoptions: {value:':;1:Best'} },
        { name:'supplier3', index:'supplier1', width:75, align:"center", sorttype:'number', stype: 'select', searchoptions: {value:':;1:Best'} }
    ],
    gridComplete:function() {
        var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');


            //coloring based on value of column best (DB calculated)
            for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

                if ( parseFloat(grid.jqGrid("getCell", ids[i], 'best_price').replace(/,/, '.')) == parseFloat(grid.jqGrid("getCell", ids[i], 'supplier1').replace(/,/, '.')) ) {
                    $(this).jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'supplier1','',{color: 'black', background: '#94FF94'});
                }

                if ( parseFloat(grid.jqGrid("getCell", ids[i], 'best_price').replace(/,/, '.')) == parseFloat(grid.jqGrid("getCell", ids[i], 'supplier2').replace(/,/, '.')) ) {
                    $(this).jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'supplier2','',{color: 'black', background: '#94FF94'});
                }                           

                if ( parseFloat(grid.jqGrid("getCell", ids[i], 'best_price').replace(/,/, '.')) == parseFloat(grid.jqGrid("getCell", ids[i], 'supplier3').replace(/,/, '.')) ) {
                    $(this).jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'supplier3','',{color: 'black', background: '#94FF94'});
                }                           

            }
    },
    rowList: [],        // disable page size dropdown
    pgbuttons: false,     // disable page control like next, back button
    pgtext: null,         // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
    viewrecords: false,    // disable current view record text like 'View 1-10 of 100'          
    rowNum: 2000,
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    toppager: true,
    footerrow:true,
    loadonce:true,
    pager: '#tbl_pager',
    sortname: 'item',
    gridview: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption: "Result"
}); 

//toolbar
grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true, searchOnEnter : true, defaultSearch:"cn"});

//buttons
grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#tbl_pager',
    { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true, cloneToTop: true }, // navGrid options
    {}, // edit option
    { reloadAfterSubmit:true}, // add options
    {}, // del options
    {multipleSearch:true}  // !!! search options !!!
);

// remove some double elements from one place which we not need double
var topPagerDiv = $('#' + grid[0].id + '_toppager')[0];         // "#list_toppager"
$("#" + grid[0].id + "_toppager_center", topPagerDiv).remove(); // "#list_toppager_center"
$(".ui-paging-info", topPagerDiv).remove();


});
</script>
```